# Displaying a method called by the user within a module & class

Tags: ruby

edit

```
class Tof
  def Tof.etiology
    puts "NS displacement of the infundibular septum"
  end
   def Tof.pathophys
    puts "VSD, Overriding of the Aorta, RVH, pulmonary stenosis"
  end
end

puts "What would you like to know?"
```

how do I get the user to type Tof.etiology, such that the puts statement displays

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, can you clarify what you expect to happen?

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way. Can you provide a more general overview of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: basically I want to have many classes with the same 7 methods each time, but leave room later on for flexibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited answer for new code in question)

You should be able to implement this with simple inheritance.

```
class Foo
   def m1
     puts "method 1"
   end
   # ...
   def m7
     puts "method 7"
   end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

class Baz < Foo
end

bar = Bar.new
bar.m1 # method 1

baz = Baz.new
baz.m1 # method 1
```

You could also make module Foo and use a mixin.

The second portion can be handled with the initial answer:

```
puts "what would you like to know?"
answer = gets.chomp

case answer
when "Tof.etiology"
  Tof.etiology
when "Tof.othermethod"
  Tof.othermethod
end
```

Comment: I want to add a method to display all the available methods under the a class, BUT each class may not have the same methods or number of methods, how would I do this more efficiently than:
`def Tof.methods`
  `puts "m1 m2 m3 m4 m5"`
`end`
...
`when "Tof"`
  `Tof.methods`